# How can I add brackets and quotes around values in a column within Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to add brackets and quotes around a column of values in Excel and I've found formulas for the quotes, and formulas for the brackets, but I can't seem to get both together.

Essentially, I want to take a value such as:

Accounting

and make it:

["Accounting"]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A1 has your value....

```
    ="["""&A1&"""]"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Isolated!